# Put all screenshots in one document with single click

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture, greenshot

I often take number of Greenshot screenshots for a particular workflow and then edit these screenshots into Greenshot Image Editor to add some text or shapes.

Is it possible to dump/store all these edited screenshots into a single document with one click? (The document can be PDF/Docx or any other common type).

This could be a great feature for those who are creating a tutorial or step by step direction. They can take screenshots, edit them and then create a document quickly. I understand that I can do copy to clipboard or save as image, but when you have number of screenshots, it becomes tedious.

I can think of Pandoc kind of library that can be used to create a document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Greenshot does have a plugin for sending screenshots directly to Microsoft Office applications - for example, Word. You can do this from the menu that appears after taking a screenshot asking where to send the image, or from the image editor.

In the context menu, if you hover over Microsoft Word, it gives you the option to insert the screenshot into an open Word document. It will be inserted wherever the caret is at the time. If you simply click on "Microsoft Word" rather than hovering, it will open a new Word document and insert it there.
[Greenshot destination context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPAql.png)

The same effect can be achieved from the editor by clicking the MS Word icon or the dropdown arrow next to it.
[Greenshot editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfotw.png)

> Is it possible to dump/store all these edited screenshots into a single document with one click?

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this, since after editing a screenshot it is generally either saved or exported somewhere rather than staying in the editor. But using the methods I've described, it is possible to have your screenshots added to a Word document one-by-one after you finish editing them.